# evaluating polynomials of matrices in python using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra, polynomials

I use sympy to operate on polynomials and matrices. But I'm looking for polynomials of matrices. After much searching online I only find results where entries of matrices are polynomials, for example the 2x2 matrix below:

x^2   x^3

x+1   x-1

However what I'm interested in, is a function which takes as input a polynomial p and a matrix M, and simply outputs p(M).

I am at a loss as to how to google this :)

Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `M**2` is the matrix product of `M`?

Comment: For example if I input x ** 2 + x + 2, and M=[[0,1],[1,0]] it should compute and output the value of

M ** 2 + M + 2I where I is the identity matrix of size same as M.

Comment: So the output should be M=[[3, 1], [1, 3]].

Comment: You can just write `M**2 + M + 2*eye(2)`.

Comment: Never mind. Got my answer on another post. Thanks y'all!